# Outlook ItemAdd event on IMAP folder fires only when folder is selected

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm running in a little problem with Outlook VBA programming, and would like to know if there's a solution, or if this is just another "known issue".

---

**Context**:

I have configured an Outlook e-mail account to access my web email provider through IMAP.  In Outlook, I can properly see my web email folders.  My provider's spam filter moves spam messages into the Spam folder.

I would like to automatically move messages that get put into the Spam folder into another folder, in my local pst file.

I have it working 99% (through the code provided below for reference).

---

**Issue**:

I can see that there are messages in the Spam folder (there is a bold unread message count beside the folder name), but the ItemAdd even will only fire when I click on the folder.  At that point, I see the contents of the spam folder, and then see all of the new spam being moved to my local folder.

Is there another trigger source beside ItemAdd I could use for running my code without having to click on the folder?  Is there an event that gets triggered when the unread count for a folder changes?

---

**Technical details**:

- Windows 8 OS
- Using Outlook 2002 (Yes, I know...)
- I'm an experienced C/C++ developer, but minimal experience in VBA, and none with Outlook.

VBA code:

```
Public WithEvents myItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Const mailboxName As String = "Mail.com"
    Const subfolderName As String = "Spam"


    ' Reference the items in the MAPI spam folder
    ' Because myOlItems is declared "WithEvents" the ItemAdd event will fire below.
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error GoTo noSpamFolder
    Set myItems = myNameSpace.Folders(mailboxName).Folders(subfolderName).Items
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

noSpamFolder:
    MsgBox "Unable to find folder <" & mailboxName & "/" & subfolderName & ">"

End Sub


Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim suspectFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    ' Check to make sure it is an Outlook mail message, otherwise
    ' subsequent code will probably fail depending on what type
    ' of item it is.
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

       ' Move message to the 'suspect' folder
       On Error GoTo noSuspectFolder
       Set suspectFolder = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("suspect")
       On Error GoTo 0

       Item.Move suspectFolder

    End If

    Exit Sub

noSuspectFolder:
    MsgBox "Unable to find folder <suspect> as a sub-folder of default inbox folder"
End Sub
```

Comment: have you gotten the script to work? i am trying to find a way for an event to fire once a calendar event is created, i guess it would be something along the lines of `Outlook.MAPIFolder.itemsAdd` but i'm not entirely sure. I have basically no experience with VBscript, maybe you can point me in the right direction...

Comment: No improvement from my initial description, which means that I still need to click on the IMAP folder for its items to be processed.  I can live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Was struggling with a similar issue to move mail-items after they were sent and used your code to perform this task (thx!). There were several issues which still had to be resolved.

First of all, the items were moved, but immediately after they were placed into the trash folder. This seems to be an IMAP issue (Gmail) and may be resolved by changing the Internet E-mail Settings of the mailbox account from "Move deleted items to the following folder on the server" to "Mark items for deletion but do not move them automatically".

The second challenge was, like yours, trigger the code to do its work. In the account configuration the save sent emails option is disabled (since this is automatically performed by the Gmail server). I needed to sync the Sent items (MAPI) folder with the Send items (IMAP) folder. **I achieved this by configuring the "send/receive" groups for this email account (in the group All account) and selecting the Sent items folder**.

Now this folder is synced without the necessity to open the folder for syncing. I hope that this will also resolve your issue.

Peter

Comment: That was the missing item, thanks!  After adding the spam folder in the IMAP account into the send/receive group, the ItemAdd event gets triggered on a refresh. :)

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense - the IMAP provider in Outlook syncs the folder only when it is selected or accesed through the Outlook Object Model.
I don't think there is much you can do short of polling the folder every once in a while (and releasing the MAPIFolder object in between the hits)

Comment: That's what I figured, but the fact that the unread count does update tells me that Outlook knows that there are new messages, even though it has not actually fetched them yet.  Any way to hook on that information?

Comment: Does MAPIFolder.FolderChange event fire on the parent folder? You can see the event in OutlookSpy (select the parent folder, click Folder button on the OutlookSpy toolbar, select Folders property, click Browse, go to the Events tab)?

Comment: I'm unable to follow your instructions, I don't seem to get what I believe you are expecting. Here is what I've done: 

1) Downloaded and installed OutlookSpy 2.15 (Not the latest, since I'm running Outlook 2002)
2) If I select the parent folder of my spam folder, clicking the Folder item on the outlook spy produces no action.  The parent folder is the main folder for the account, and in the main Outlook window, I have the message "Unable to display the folder.  This is the root of an IMAP store.  The root does not contain messages but may have subfolders that do ..."

Comment: 3) If I select my spam folder first, clicking on OutlookSpy's Folder button produces a "MAPIFolder" dialog.  Then clicking on Browse... just seems to produce another copy of the dialog.  Neither has an Events tab, they only have the Properties, Functions and Script tabs.

Comment: After you click The Folder button, select the Folders (note the plural) property, then click Browse.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and the precision.  Re-reading your original instructions, they are perfectly clear.  This addresses my 3) item, I can now see events when I select the Spam folder, but that would be the Spam.folders events, so probably not useful.  Your original instructions were to get the event for the spam's parent folder, but I'm still unable, as per my 2), to get any reaction from the Folder button on the toolbar when my IMAP main folder is selected (my spam folder is directly under the main folder).

Comment: You can try to access the folder programmatically - if I remembeer correctly, that causes teh sync. If that does not work, try to make the folder selected (set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder, then select the old folder again.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, however the issue is trying to trigger the move activity without resorting to regular polling that would be timer controlled.  If I resort to a polling method, then I don't need the ItemAdd event, I'll just move any existing messages in the folder at every poll.  I was looking for a way to trigger the operation automatically whenever Outlook shows a non-zero unread count.  It looks like the answer is that VBA does not provide a way to do this.